# If $x$,$y$,$z > 0$, $k > 2$ and $a = x+ky+kz$, $b = kx+y+kz$, $c = kx+ky+z$, show that $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c} ≥ \frac{3}{2k+1}$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $x$, $y$, $z > 0$, $k > 2$ and $a = x+ky+kz$, $b = kx+y+kz$, $c = kx+ky+z$, show that $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c} ≥ \frac{3}{2k+1}$ .

**What I'd tried :**

$$a = x+ky+kz\dots(1)$$
$$b = kx+y+kz\dots(2)$$
$$c = kx+ky+z\dots(3)$$
From (1),(2) and (3),

$$a-x+b-y+c-z=2k(x+y+z)$$
or, $2k+1 = \frac{a+b+c}{x+y+z}$

So the given inequality becomes $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c} ≥ \frac{3(x+y+z)}{a+b+c}$ or,
$\frac{x}{a}-\frac{x+y+z}{a+b+c}+\frac{y}{b}-\frac{x+y+z}{a+b+c}+\frac{z}{c}-\frac{x+y+z}{a+b+c} ≥ 0$

*From here things start getting really complicated to prove*...

Comment: see this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h524301p11362002